# Draw a quadratic arc over IplImage

Tags: opengl, opencv, draw, quadratic

I currently have an iplimage that has been modified using opencv. I am needing to draw an arc like that of the parabola of a quadratic equation, and I am unable to make one using the basic drawing functions built into opencv. I have been looking into opengl, but all I can find are bezier curves. What would be the best library to use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend moving to OpenGL (based upon what you've provided in the post).

If you want to take a simple approach, you can solve the quadratic equation point-by-point (i.e. assume x is the independent variable and then solve for y).  Once both x and y are known, you can draw the color at the specified point.  I've provided a snippet below that illustrates a method for coloring a pixel in OpenCV.  Take this code as it is: it worked for me, but it does not take into account any anti-aliasing, transparency, sub-pixel accuracy, etc.

```
void overlay(IplImage *o, const IplImage *m, const CvScalar &color)
{
  CvSize size = cvGetSize(o);

  unsigned char *p1 = NULL;
  unsigned char *p2 = NULL;

  for (size_t r=0;r<size_t(size.height);r++)
    for (size_t c=0;c<size_t(size.width);c++)
      {
        p1 = cvPtr2D(m, r, c);
        if (p1[0] == 255)
          {
            p2 = cvPtr2D(o, r, c);

            p2[0] = color.val[0];   // R
            p2[1] = color.val[1];   // G
            p2[2] = color.val[2];   // B
          }
      }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use <strike>OpenCV's Bezier curve support</strike> third-party libraries for Bezier curve support in OpenCV. I've experimented with [this one](https://github.com/thenatefisher/OpenCV-Beziers) in the past.  With a little computation, you can represent arbitrary conic sections using weighted Bezier curves.  Take a look at the Rational Bezier Curves section near the bottom of the wikipedia page: [Bezier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

Comment: OpenCV supports bezier curves?

Comment: @Jacob: Good catch - I don't believe they are natively supported.  I've experimented with 3rd party stuff in the past. Answer edited.

Comment: I currently have the x and y values of about 7 points that are on the parabola and I know the equation. I guess Ill just fill in the points of the lines between the ones I know.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/superap/code/basicwindow.c) on [this](http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/superap/opengl.html) page. It works and I am sure that if I can not figure out how to convert an iplimage to something glut can use I can apply this algorithm in opencv, for it is very similar to what is mentioned <strike>below</strike> above.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV cvEllipse is all you need for that. Just take care on how to use parameters.

cvEllipse(CvArr* img, CvPoint center, CvSize axes, double angle, double startAngle, double endAngle, CvScalar color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0 )